# How to export flutter app from android studio to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter

I have an application running on Android, and it's on play store already.
Now I want to start deploying to Appstore,I managed to get a Mac for this.
I'm trying to import the project to Xcode,but `flutter run` gives errors for different paths of flutter and packages.

Is there an easy way to export from Windows and Android studio to Mac Xcode and not wasting hours only to open the project?

EDIT:
The error it gives: Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established. The following Dart file:
/Users/bojke/Desktop/app/lib/main.dart ...refers, in an import, to the following library: /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud-firestore-0.8.2+3/lib/cloud_firestore.dart
Unfortunately, that library does not appear to exist on your file system.

That's because I can't name a directory with doubledot..

Thanks!

Comment: Running 'flutter run' from the root directory of your Flutter project works for iOS and Android. Please edit your question and tell us more about the errors that you are getting.

Comment: I have edited my question,please take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot to do:
`flutter packages get` . This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You don't "export from Android Studio to Xcode". The flutter project contains the projects for both native problems. Run

```
flutter build ios --release
```

Then go into the iOS project and open your Runner workspace for iOS then archive your project from there.

Once you're in the xcode project [follow these instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

Comment: I'm not sure it would work on Ios, I have to add some exceptions,and test it. How am I able to open the source code?

Comment: @Bojke it definitely works on iOS. I've made numerous apps this way. After running your build command you open the Runner workspace file in your iOS projec ( ios/Runner.xcworkspace). That will open it in xcode and you can make custom changes to your project settings from there.

Answer (score 0):

Connection to physical iPhone device is not necessary. Run any sample project in xcode. Start a Simulator. (Only One simulator preferrably).

1. clone the repository from github into Mac (with X-Code Installed)
2. open terminal.
3. cd to your pubspec.yaml
4. flutter run (it will automatically run flutter pub get) (It will launch on the already running iOS simulator)

follow steps on flutter.dev to install flutter. Above steps will only work from terminal if flutter doctor(any flutter command) is recognized

Comment: It's necessary if you need to test functionality tied multiple touches of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend installing Android Studio on your Mac and run your app on an iOS simulator or real iOS device from Android Studio. 
Make sure everything works fine, and only then build for release.

Here is a [step by step instruction on how to set up your Mac environment for Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)

And when you feel your app is ready for the open-world - check out this doc on [how to build and release an iOS app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

Also, if you don't have a Mac you can start a virtual machine with Mac OS X, hosted on your Windows or Linux. It will give you the ability to run your Flutter app both on iOS simulator and on physical iOS devices, as well as Android emulator/real device.

For example, I have an OS X Mohave running on my host Windows 8.1 on VMware. Make sure you have enough RAM and CPU to run both OS. I allocated 6GB of RAM to the virtual machine and it runs at a speed enough to make some fixes for iOS, run on iPhone simulator and release a build on XCode. 
Clearly it would be annoying to work at that speed all the time but for my purposes its enough.

If you don't want to mess around with virtual machine - check https://www.macincloud.com/ it's a cloud service for getting remote access to a dedicated Mac.  (with XCode installed) for $20/mo. For 8 hours per day, it's something like $35/mo. 
Good as a temporary solution if you don't want to spend $2k for a MacBook Pro